# Python requests 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to log in to a cloudflare server based website. I bypassed the login issues using cloudserver, but my next stop point has been when I tried to send a get request to have access to some post login tokens.

My code:

```
headers = {
          'authority': 'www.paf.es',
          'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36',
          'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
          'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
          'referer': 'https://www.paf.es/my-paf',
          'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
          'cookie': '__cfduid=d4247b3fce5d260d7c5257b5d65a572001592254859; com.paf.frontend.common.LocaleCookie=es_ES; _gcl_au=1.1.193127229.1592254863; _ga=GA1.2.484179826.1592254863; _gid=GA1.2.1016568931.1592254863; _fbp=fb.1.1592254863595.468566668; com.paf.frontend.cookiesAccepted=true; com.paf.frontend.common.device=desktop; __cf_bm=10366cb3cb936cf0d9188cdf37dfaf276961f164-1592257614-1800-AbXayDicXL3zBDecjcoUuzlv+Qb5YhjhhqZO6goD80+W/J7ahYM+mwNHdcav405NnNOcPxyErOcdvPzijcdXGhk=; BIGipServerprod01_pool=1067697930.22811.0000; _gat_UA-641842-15=1; com.paf.frontend.common.showMenu=account; _gali=loginButton; JSESSIONID=tuO580BlkBaMw5v3txOBy0v2hqQV-61ZBQCVRqdqcTEQN4-5Z6tuu0021151447412; com.paf.frontend.common.LoginTime=1592257626364; com.paf.frontend.common.LoggedIn=true; __cfruid=5fe9d18ceeda0612668c20982f65d634686cb526-1592227626; com.paf.frontend.common.LifeCycleCookie=HAS_LOGGED_IN; trackingParams={"_ga":{"value":"GA1.2.484179826.1592254863","expiration":1600033627916},"utm_nooverride":{"value":"1","expiration":1600033627916}}; com.paf.frontend.common.LocaleCookie=es_ES; JSESSIONID=m4650rp-X0aJYw_6b8-3ghQIOU-h1luYOQV4dAwZz6UGVc4RanvZ!151447412; com.paf.frontend.common.LoginTime=1592255494930; com.paf.frontend.common.LoggedIn=true; __cfruid=3ffb40834f313a4c2b4d351r24f9a946uu5f7db9-1592255495'
        }
cloudserver.get(url=url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps({}))
```

This returns 401 being the answer:

```
The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.46) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity MAY include relevant diagnostic information.
```

and its headers are

```
{'Date': 'Wed, 17 Jun 2020 23:56:04 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'CF-Ray': '5a50b4816fddd665-MAD', 'Set-Cookie': 'com.paf.frontend.common.LocaleCookie=es_ES; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2021 23:56:04 GMT; path=/, com.paf.frontend.common.LoggedIn=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/, __cf_bm=73f0a2b2216d419f8a19f3e8ff74e8eca2458229-1592438164-1800-AaPuIPRQVOJGvI9l1DBiMeXXmyczqpm7Owaf2XUHFqZ+FJ9PT44TdL4kxAU4FCOWDWQmztz9Ff1FTHrCcDQw88w=; path=/; expires=Thu, 18-Jun-20 00:26:04 GMT; domain=.paf.es; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '03664f24e50000d66506af8200000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=86400'}
```

Ok so I first tried to give an auth. Like this

```
s.get(url=url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps({}),auth=HTTPBasicAuth('somemail@mail.com','password'))
```

And I get again the same error, a 401, but this time the headers of the response do have a www-authenticate I'm supposed to challenge

```
{'Date': 'Wed, 17 Jun 2020 23:58:42 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'CF-Ray': '5a50b85dd8fdd665-MAD', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="weblogic"', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '0366518ea80000d66506a1b200000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Set-Cookie': '__cf_bm=c153a7277cf7abbaa004cdb46da821906f04b7c6-1592438322-1800-AR+KhjkQM5NHTTqKA0scqXrUGJpKNOnG0ZASOG386zEILi28YAh28BV+pWYGXzly+7ptsr9TJSGurY2nBOTv75I=; path=/; expires=Thu, 18-Jun-20 00:28:42 GMT; domain=.paf.es; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=86400'}
```

From what I have read, it being basic meant that I have to add to my headers a key like this `'Authentication': "Basic fhsejdjsjejdsj"` being the string after the Basic a base64 encoding of 'username:password'.

However, with this addition to my header I send a request again and I'm still stuck in the same point, with the same 401.

My questions would be, in the 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="weblogic"' does it matter what is after realm? How can I overcome this and be able to complete my request?

Comment: Why dont use requests.get instead?

Comment: I don't understand, instead of what

Comment: Use requests lib, you can google python requests lib for usage

Comment: cloudserver is a requests based library. It is used for bypassing 403 that cloudflare gives to requests. If you use a regular requests for this get query you still get 401

Comment: Have you tried running your get request in Postman? The issue looks like its down to headers (as appose to Python code). Also in you headers you have authentication, but I think the correct word is Authorization e.g: "Authorization": "Basic abcde"

Answer (score 4):

Just in case the HTTP authentication is not clearly understood here I'll explain how it works.

1. You request a HTTP resource in an usual way, with all headers you think you will need
2. If the content or area (i.e. realm) is password protected, the server returns 401 error. The response contains the WWW-Authenticate header which tells you which authentication method you have to use when responding to the server and to what realm it applies.
3. If you receive the 401, you repeat your request to the server but you add the Authorization header to the request. Its content varies according to the method being used i.e. the one being requested by the server in the first response. For the basic authentication method your authorization should have the word Basic as the first "argument", then the username and password separated using colon ":" sign, but this string must be Base64 encoded. You can do:

   headers["Authorization"] = "Basic "+(("%s:%s" % (username, password)).encode("base64")

This is designed to support browsers and a GUI dialogs. When a browser receives 401 it pops up a dialog asking you for username and password. When you click OK, it repeats the request with Authorization header added to it. From this point onward, the browser always sends the Authorization header to continue being logged-in, until another 401 is received for another realm. Realm is used so that the browser can change credentials automatically doring the session according to the realm server is requesting, without prompting you to enter them again each time the same realm is requested. That's because you may have different areas of files protected with different passwords, or multiple accounts on the same server and so on.

Now, for security and standardization reasons a server might always refuse a first request, regardless if it receives Authorization header already. In fact, it may see it as the security breach if you send the Authorization before the WWW-Authenticate wasn't requested. Some servers will sent it once and expect Authorization being present from this point on, and only repeat 401 if it disappears from further requests from a client. Other will always send 401 then expect the repeated request. Some will also cut off your access completely, and you will receive the 403 Forbidden if you send the incorrect credentials e.g. 3 times in a row. Also, if the server is using the basic authentication, this most usually means that the server is using HTTPS, not HTTP. As the sent data is easy to intercept and read on a HTTP link, if HTTP is used, some other, encrypted, method will be asked to preserve security. So, the server might also refuse you if you send Authorization header with basic method through the HTTP instead of HTTPS.

The feature of the server I described above (HTTP standard auth procedure) is the reason you sometimes get in and sometimes you receive 401 again. The method you deal with this is to never send Authorization header unless you receive 401 first. Using urllib to deal with this is easy because a HTTPError() will be raised for the 401 Unauthorized. So you would just:

```
def get (*args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop("user", "")
    pwd  = kwargs.pop("pwd", "")
    r = Request(*args, **kwargs) # A request with URL and headers and data
    try:
        u = urlopen(r)
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.code==401 and "WWW-Authenticate" in e.headers:
            if not e.headers.get("WWW-Authenticate").lower().startswith("basic "):
                raise
            r.add_header("Authorization", "Basic "+(user+":"+pwd).encode("base64"))
            u = urlopen(r)
        else:
            raise
    c = u.read()
    u.close()
    return c
```

You need to see whether the server sends 401 each time or only once. As you are using requests you will have to check for a response code using the responses attribute without try-except block. Or switch to stdlib urllib/urllib2.
This is what I would do as it seems you are not using features from requests like sessions anyway, but sending cookies each time manually.

The real question here is what auth is expected from JSON and what from HTTP headers. Are both needed or only one of them. You will just have to experiment. It looks to me as the API performs the HTTP authentication even if you only send credentials through data. But...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so something I tried seems to have worked partially. Just to recap, I tried everything:

Adding `Authorization: Basic <token>` to the headers of the request

Adding `Authorization: Bearer <token>` to the headers of the request

Using `auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password)` in the request

Using `auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username,password)` in the request

Nothing seemed to work. Just as a reminder, I use cloudscraper instead of a regular requests because the server is in cloudflare and otherwise returned 403.

So, what actually worked was to reuse the headers used in the login attempt. So instead of this

```
s=cloudscraper.create_scraper()
s.post(url=url,headers=headers,data=payload) #Being url the XHR for the login, headers the ones from postman, and  data a string with my actual username and password
s.get(url=url,headers=headers) #New url requests and new headers from postman
```

I did this

```
s=cloudscraper.create_scraper()
s.post(url=url,headers=headers,data=payload)
s.get(url=url) #no headers here, just a reuse from the ones in the previous request
```

This isn't perfect, as sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, for no reason and posting the exact same parameters in the exact same order. But, it is a progress

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure which library you're using here, but assuming the library is based on Requests, the way I'm reading this is:

You attempt to send a request to the server, which fails with a 401 error. This means your request lacked the necessary credentials to access what you're trying to access.

So you send another request with a username and password.

The server replies with another 401 error, which still means the same thing: Your request lacked the necessary credentials to access what you're trying to access.

Given the response header provided by the server: `'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="weblogic"'`, you're correct that you need to use basic authentication.

The weblogic realm is the area the server is telling you need to log in to. Your request needs to have a valid username and password for that realm on that server.

Again assuming that your library is based on Requests, you don't need to base64 anything yourself, this call:

```
s.get(url=url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps({}),auth=HTTPBasicAuth('somemail@mail.com','password'))
```

or this shorthand version:

```
s.get(url=url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps({}),auth=('somemail@mail.com','password'))
```

will handle that for you, but you need a valid username and password combination.

Comment: Yes, cloudscraper is based on requests. It's like requests.session. I already did what you suggested, but the 401 still prevails. What have somewhat worked is, provded that the `s=cloudscrsper.create_scraper()` is a requests session, reuse the headers of the login instead of adding in the s.get request. Problem is this sometimes works, sometimes still gets 401, and I'm not sure why is that